# rEFInd boot manager not showing EFI shell

Tags: macos, startup, efi

After succesfully installing the rEFInd tool from https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/ on a macbook with macos 10.15, restarting the laptop does bring me into the rEFInd boot manager. But the only option available is to launch macOS. I downloaded this tool to use the EFI shell and there seems to be no option to launch the shell.

Is this some sort of package I need to install to the EFI mount?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a compatible EFI Shell program (called `shell.efi`) in your EFI partition.

As mentioned in the rEFInd config file [documentation](https://rodsbooks.com/refind/configfile.html#adjusting), in the showtools parameter section:

> Note that the shell, memtest, gdisk, apple_recovery, mok_tool, and fwupdate options all require the presence of programs not included with rEFInd.

The rEFInd CD version *does* include an EFI shell (there is also a link for it on the [Installing Additional Components](https://rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html#addons) section of the documentation) but this doesn't work on my macs (all 2015 or older) as the Apple EFI firmware is too old.

You can download an older EDK version 1 binary which should work on any version :

- Download `Shell_Full.efi` from [tianocore/edk2](https://github.com/tianocore/edk2/blob/UDK2018/EdkShellBinPkg/FullShell/X64/Shell_Full.efi)
- Rename it to `shell.efi`
- Mount your ESP with `mkdir /Volumes/ESP` followed by `sudo mount -t msdos /dev/disk0s1 /Volumes/ESP`
- Copy `shell.efi` to directory `/Volumes/ESP/EFI/tools` where rEFInd will look by default (make directory if it doesn't exist).
- rEFInd will display shell as a small icon underneath the OS icons if it finds the executable.

Comment: *"The CD version"*... of what? rEFInd?

Comment: @Seamus - the rEFInd CD version, yes.  On the rEFInd [downloads page](https://sourceforge.net/projects/refind/files/0.12.0/) there are releases in various formats - binary, image to dd onto usb key and a bootable CD image file to burn onto optical disk.  Only the CD image contains a `boot.efi` but it is a version 2 `boot.efi` which doesn't work on mac (at least not on mine).  I updated the answer to hopefully clarify.

Comment: Thnx - I didn't know rEFInd even *had* a 'CD version'.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to use the EFI shell included in rEFIt, the discontinued predecessor to rEFInd: http://refit.sourceforge.net/

The archive refit-bin-0.14.tar.gz includes a file called shell.efi that you can copy to your EFI/tools folder.

Thanks to Wayne Uroda's answer on superuser.com, I was able to install the latest NVidia drivers on my Macmini3,1 (late 2009), which now triple boots macOS, Windows 10 64-bit and MX Linux, all booting with EFI with a GPT (no hybrid MBR) and rEFInd.

[Answer on superuser.com that helped me](https://superuser.com/a/1544479/1257661)

Comment: Hey! I'm glad I could help you! No upvote for me over there on superuser though!?! ;)